# Is it OK to have a public final instance field in a JPA Entity if that field is not intended to be persisted (@Transient, etc)?

Tags: java, jpa

As I read JPA 2.1 specification it looks like all instance fields shall be public, regardless of whether they shall be persisted to the database or not.

For final, is seems that only persisted instance fields cannot be final, but I am not 100% sure.

Hence the question.

P.S. I understand that public fields is almost always bad.

Comment: 'As I read JPA 2.1 specification it looks like all instance fields shall be public' - I'm 99,99% sure the specification does **not** say that, could you please point out which statements in the spec lead you to this conclusion?

Comment: Regarding your question, the spec says that 'No [...] **persistent** instance variables of the entity class may be final'. JPA simply ignores `@Transient` fields, and so it doesn't really care how they are configured. It does require a no-args constructor, though, meaning the field will need an initializing expression that is independent of any constructor parameters. Thus, I imagine in most cases, you could just make it `static final`